# grunt-contrib-sass: How do I add a subfolder into the destination dynamically?

Tags: sass, grunt-contrib-sass

I have a directory structure of:

- `views`

  - `_static_`

    - `some.js`
  - `somesass.scss`
  - `something.jade`

I was hoping to do something like this:

    `sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'views',
          src: ['*/*.scss'],
          flatten: true,
          dest: 'views/*/_static_',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },`

If I just do `dest: 'views'` and remove `flatten:true` then it, at least, puts it in the same folder the .scss file is in, but I can't figure out how to say "ok, add '`_static_`' to the cwd of the current file and place the .css in there." How/can I do that with grunt-contrib-sass?

If wondering why I'm not just throwing all the compiled CSS into one directory, it's because this is for an experimentation server for myself, so I'm not minifying or anything.

Comment: According to [this](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) `dest:` is a path prefix, so no suffixes, but the next documented param `rename` looks promising.

Comment: That just might work. Thanks Kenny. :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I'll post the answer in a bit for anyone else that may be trying to do similar.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the sub-folder into the path I had to use `rename: function(dest, src){ .. }`, but things didn't work as I would assume. First off, `flatten` is not what is wanted so we can get at the parent directory through src. The other thing to be aware of is that `src` inside `rename:` will have `whatever.css` as the file, even if the `src` outside is defined as `['*/*.scss']`. That works in our favor, but tripped me up because I expected to see `whatever.scss`. I still need to go back and work on it some, but this got the job done for me:

`sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'views',
          src: ['*/*.scss'],
          rename: function(dest, src) {
            // src will have .css extension, not scss.
            var splitPath = src.split('/');
            // Leaves the path preceding the filename in splitPath.
            var filename = splitPath.pop(); 
            // There shouldn't be any other subdirectories, 
            // but added j.i.c. until I can come back to it.
            var joinedPath = splitPath.join("/"); 
            var customDest = this.cwd + '/' + joinedPath + '/_static_/' + filename;
            return customDest;
          },
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }`

The end result is:

- `views`

  - `_static_`

    - `some.js`
    - `somesass.css` (ends up at the custom location after running `grunt sass`)
  - `somesass.scss` (the source Sass)
  - `something.jade`